# Python how to install the itertools module on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, python

I am new to Python. I wanted to try out the itertools package from Python. But I got the error:

`NameError: global name 'itertools' is not defined`

How to resolve this error? Do I need to install this module?
I have included `from itertools import *`.

How to install this module? Where do I find the `itertools` module/package? I searched on google but it kept referring to documentation page of `itertools`.

I am using Debian 6. I have Python 2.6.

Comment: I've just installed Debian 6.0.8 in a VM, the default python then is 2.6.6. And I could just 'import itertools' without any problem. Which exact debian version and python version are you using?

Comment: @brm I tried `import itertools` instead of `from itertools import *` and it worked fine. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: No idea. Both work just fine here

Comment: for `redhat distros` I recommend using `yum` to install python packages. if you are missing the package, then I would recommend an install via debian's package manager.